# Removing a div as user removes input in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, html, createelement

I'm trying to take user input, match result, display result in drop-down, and then click on a name from drop down to display it. I've been able to display result in drop-down using innerHTML but it wasn't clickable so now I'm dynamically creating Div elements. However, I'm not sure how to clear the list when user presses backspace. I was previously doing that with **document.getElementById('placeholder').innerHTML=""** statement.  Here's what I've done so far. The code in comments is for when I was displaying the drop down menu using innerHTML:

HTML code:

```
<body>
  <input id="filter" type="text" placeholder="Enter your filter text here.."
   onkeyup="test()"/>

  <div id="lc">  
    <!--- <p id='placeholder'> </p>  -->
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/filter.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS code:

```
 // JavaScript Document
 s1 = new String()
 var myArray = new Array();

 myArray[0] = "Donald Duck";
 myArray[1] = "Winnie Pooh";
 myArray[2] = "Komal Waseem";
 myArray[3] = "Hockey";
 myArray[4] = "Basketball";
 myArray[5] = "Shooting";
 myArray[6] = "Mickey Mouse";

 function test() {
   s1 = document.getElementById('filter').value;
   var myRegex = new RegExp((s1),"ig");
   arraysearch(myRegex);
 }

 function arraysearch(myRegex) { 
   var flag=0;

   //document.getElementById('placeholder').innerHTML=""; 
   for(i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) { 
   //if(myArray[i].charAt(0).indexOf(s1) != -1) {
     if(myArray[i].match(myRegex)) { 
       flag = 1;
       //document.getElementById('lc').style.visibility = 'visible';
       //document.getElementById('placeholder').innerHTML += myArray[i]+"<br/>";
       var element = document.createElement("div");
       element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myArray[i]));
       document.getElementById('lc').appendChild(element);
     }
   //}

   if (flag == 0) {
     document.getElementById('lc').style.visibility='hidden';
   }
 }
```

Comment: If you're not sure, why not use an existing autocomplete solution? There are plenty available on the web.

Comment: not interested in jquery? could make your life a lot easier...

Comment: Yes I've looked at the jquery plugins and solutions but want to implement this through javascript.

Comment: @KomalWaseem: Use the `onclick` element attribute if the element is created from a string that is passed to `innerHTML`. Otherwise, simply assign the element's `onclick` property.